# Zip Archive With Limited Number of Files

Tags: files, zip

What command can I use to create `zip`s with a file number limit? I have a folder (no subfolders) of, say, 5000 files, so I would want a command that could divide that number and create 10 individual `zip` archives, each consisting of no more than 500 files.

I also don't want the resulting 10 `zip` files to be connected with each other, so that I can open them individually and won't need to open all 10 at the same time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) to do that as it can limit the number of elements to a job as well as provide a job number (for a unique zip archive name):

```
$ touch $(seq 20)
$ find . ! -name "*.zip" -type f -print0 | parallel -0 -N 5 zip arch{#} {}
  adding: 1 (stored 0%)
  adding: 10 (stored 0%)
  adding: 11 (stored 0%)
  adding: 12 (stored 0%)
  adding: 13 (stored 0%)
  adding: 14 (stored 0%)
  adding: 15 (stored 0%)
  adding: 16 (stored 0%)
  adding: 17 (stored 0%)
  adding: 18 (stored 0%)
  adding: 19 (stored 0%)
  adding: 2 (stored 0%)
  adding: 20 (stored 0%)
  adding: 3 (stored 0%)
  adding: 4 (stored 0%)
  adding: 5 (stored 0%)
  adding: 6 (stored 0%)
  adding: 7 (stored 0%)
  adding: 8 (stored 0%)
  adding: 9 (stored 0%)
$ ls
1   11  13  15  17  19  20  4  6  8  arch1.zip  arch3.zip
10  12  14  16  18  2   3   5  7  9  arch2.zip  arch4.zip
```

The option `-N 5` limits the number of files to 5 per archive and is presented to `zip` in place of `{}`

The `{#}` (verbatim, not to be replaced by you during the invocation), is replaced by the job number, resulting in `arch1.zip`, `arch2.zip` etc.

The `-print0` option to `find` and `-0` option to `parallel` in tandem make sure that filenames with special characters are correctly handled.

Comment: I got this error: http://i.imgur.com/JoyPrfY.png From this command: find * ! -name "*.zip" -type f -print0 | parallel -0 -N 500 zip arch{13} {}

Comment: @user8547 that is not GNU parallel, but the parallel included in moreutils, you best compile and install from source to get the latest security patches. http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/parallel/parallel-latest.tar.bz2

Comment: @Anthon Is this the right program: http://i.imgur.com/iVv9uNq.png

Comment: @user8547 No, either follow the link in my previous comment (http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/parallel/parallel-latest.tar.bz2) or follow the guidelines in the link to the page I provided at the top of my answer.

Comment: @user8547 no, just run `sudo apt-get install parallel`.

Comment: @Anthon It worked, but the resulting zip files have a jpg extension. When I rename the extension to zip they extract successfully.

Comment: @user8547 I only get `.jpg` name ZIP files if I do: `find * ! -name "*.zip" -type f -print0 | parallel -0 -N 5 zip {#}.jpg {}`, i.e. if I provide an extension of `.jpg to the first argument (== name of zip file)

Comment: @Anthon http://i.imgur.com/AKFpViq.png And the command I used: find * ! -name "*.zip" -type f -print0 | parallel -0 -N 500 zip arch{13} {}

Comment: @user8547 why `arch{13}`? You really need to use the `#` character. What shell are you using?

Comment: @Anthon Ah I see now. My mistake. I thought I had to input the number of zip files I wanted in place of the # sign. I just tried it again and it worked perfectly. It zipped 6273 files in 20 seconds.

Comment: @user8547 No that is the way to tell parallel to put the job number there, glad it worked out.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer worked perfectly fine for me. :) BUT, in case you don't have access to parallel (who knows why), here's an alternative I had come up with before:

```
find . ! -name '*.zip' -type f | xargs -n 500 | awk '{system("zip myarch"NR".zip "$0)}'
```

Which will create myarch1.zip, myarch2.zip, myarch3.zip, etc
You might want to use the -0 trick Anthon suggested, if you have weird filenames.

Answer (score 1):

A shell-only alternative: process batches of *COUNT* files via `"${@:START:COUNT}"` (range of positional parameters) and `shift COUNT` while incrementing a counter `c` to name the archives:

```
set -- *
c=1
while (($#)); do
  if [ $# -ge COUNT ]; then
    zip ${c}.zip "${@:1:COUNT}"
    c=$((c+1))
    shift COUNT
  else
    zip ${c}.zip "${@}"
    shift $#
  fi
done
```