# ZIP files with size limit

Tags: command, zip

Is there a command to create multiple ZIP files based on file size? So that in a folder of 600 files, totalling 1 GB, the command will create 4 zips roughly equal to 250mb.

There's a similar command [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166976/zip-archive-with-limited-number-of-files). But it ZIPs files according to a file number limit.

I also don't want the resulting zip files to be connected with each other, so that I can open them individually and won't need to open all of them at the same time.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're looking for [`zipsplit`](http://www.info-zip.org/mans/zipsplit.html), it does pretty much what you're asking for. You'd create a ZIP file containing all your files, and then split it into files according to your requirements with `zipsplit`.

Something like:

```
zip -9 myfile.zip *
zipsplit -n 250000000 myfile.zip
```

would produce `myfile1.zip`, `myfile2.zip` etc., all independent of each other, and none larger than 250MB (in powers of ten). `zipsplit` will even try to organise the contents so that each resulting archive is as close as possible to the maximum size...

`zipsplit` is part of [Info-ZIP's Zip](http://www.info-zip.org/Zip.html), which is available as the `zip` package in all Linux distributions. The archives it produces are standard ZIP files; they can be opened without issue using other ZIP-compatible tools on other platforms.