# How to split larger zip file into smaller chunks using linux command

Tags: zip

I have a zip file which is size of 1gb. I have to split this zip file into smaller chunks with the zip format of size 600mb.

Tried below command:

```
split -n 600m source.zip
```

But output file is not in zip format. I want output file in same zip format. How i can achive this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ZIP files with size limit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198982/zip-files-with-size-limit)

Comment: Is zipsplit will work larger than 15gb of zip file also?is there any size limit?

Answer (score 3):

There may be other ways to do this, but this is how I'd do it.

This solution presupposes that you have both `zip` and `unzip` installed. They are usually installed by default with any major distro that I know of. If you're not sure if you have them installed, the `which` command works.

```
which zip
which unzip
```

(Both of those should be in `/usr/bin/`. If they're not already installed, they're almost certainly in your default repos and can be installed with your package manager.)

---

Open your terminal and navigate to the directory where you store the file.

Run:

```
mkdir folder_name
unzip file_name.zip -d folder_name
zip -r -s <desired file size in megabytes>M new_file_name.zip folder_name/*
```

The expected output of these files will be `new_file_name.z01 new_file_name.z02 ... new_file_name.zip`, all of which are zip files. To open the files, simply open the `new_file_name.zip` and it will automatically open/extract the associated parts.

As the original question mentioned they wanted a 600mb part, this should create two files with one being 600mb and the second part being the remainder. You can change the `<desired file size in megabytes>` to suit your particular needs.

**EDIT:** In case it's not clear, replace the obvious with the obvious, such as file/folder names and the desired output size(s).

Comment: How we can extract new_file_name.z01 file. unzip is not working. Can you suggest me any linux command?

Comment: You don't extract file.z01. You extract file.zip and it automatically extracts .z01, z02, etc.