# Splitting the ordered list into sublists

Tags: bash, shell-script, sox

I have a list of files with names `prefix_0000.mp3` ... `prefix_x.mp3`, where max(x) = 9999.

I have the bash script:

```
...
sox prefix_*.mp3 script_name_output.mp3 # this fails because maximum number is 348
rm prefix_*.mp3
...
```

How can I best split the ordered list of mp3 files into sublists (with retaining ordering) and gradually `sox` them and remove unneeded files in a bash script?

Comment: Maximum number of what is 348?

Comment: @choroba of files

Comment: Does your system provide the `xargs` command?

Comment: @don_crissti It's Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @don_crissti `sox FAIL formats: can't open input file `x.wav': Too many open files`

Comment: Weird... I'm not familiar with `sox` but apparently [when joining files you can split the whole list into smaller sublists and run them separately, joining the results.](https://sourceforge.net/p/sox/mailman/message/27438906/)... If so there's a [similar question here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/166976) - it's about zipping files but the major difference is that  you need to join the resulting pieces too and remove them thereafter but that should be trivial...

Comment: @xralf: The problem occurs because in Ubuntu and some other Linux distributions, the number of open files per process is limited to 1024 *by default*. Run e.g. `ulimit -n 10240` before running the `sox` command to raise the limit (to the maximum any user is allowed to raise it, by default), and you should avoid the error altogether.

Comment: @NominalAnimal - I had advised the same in a (now deleted) comment however it seems it's not a system limitation but rather a [`sox` limitation...](http://superuser.com/questions/571463/how-do-i-append-a-bunch-of-wav-files-while-retaining-not-zero-padded-numeric#comment699226_571468)

Comment: @don_crissti: Really? Incredible! I do trust you, I just mean such limitations are not only stupid, but unreasonable; I'd have expected more from sox developers. Well, there is a simple workaround to splitting the list in Bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, gather the list into a Bash array. If the files are in the current directory, you can use

```
files=(prefix_????.mp3)
```

Alternatively, you can use find and sort,

```
IFS=$'\n' ;
files=($(find . -name 'prefix_*.mp3' printf '%p\n' | sort -d))
```

Setting `IFS` tells Bash to split only at newlines. If your file and directory names do not contain spaces, you can omit it.

Alternatively, you can read the file names from a file, say `filelist`, one name per line, and no empty lines,

```
IFS=$'\n'
files=($(<filelist))
```

If you might have empty lines in there, use

```
IFS=$'\n'
files=($(sed -e '/$/ d' filelist))
```

Next, decide how many files you want in each slice, the name of the temporary accumulator file, as well as the final combined file name:

```
s=100
src="combined-in.mp3"
out="combined-out.mp3"
```

Then, we just need to slice the list, and process each sublist:

```
while (( ${#files[@]} > 0 )); do
    n=${#files[@]}

    # Slice files array into sub and left.
    if (( n <= s )); then
        sub=("${files[@]}")
        left=()
    else
        (( n-= s ))
        sub=("${files[@]:0:s}")
        left=("${files[@]:s:n}")
    fi

    # If there is no source file, but there is
    # a sum file, rename sum to source.
    if [ ! -e "$src" -a -e "$out" ]; then
        mv -f "$out" "$src"
    fi

    # If there is a source file, include it first.
    if [ -e "$src" ]; then
        sub=("$src" "${sub[@]}")
    fi

    # Run command.
    if ! sox "${sub[@]}" "$out" ; then
        rm -f "$out"
        echo "Failed!"
        break
    fi

    rm -f "$src"
    echo "Done up to ${sub[-1]}."
    files=("${left[@]}")

    # rm -f "${sub[@]}"
done
```

If `sox` reports a failure, the loop will break early. Otherwise, it will output the last name in the batch processed.

We use an `if` for the `sox` command to detect the failure, and remove the output file if indeed a failure occurred. Because we also postpone modifying the `files` array until after a successful `sox` command, we can safely edit/fix individual files, and then just rerun the `while` loop, to continue where we stopped.

If you are short on disk space, you can uncomment the second-to-last line, `rm -f "${sub[@]}"`, to remove all files that have been successfully combined.

---

The above processes the initial parts over and over again.

As I explained in a comment below, the results will be much better if you concatenate the files first using `ffmpeg` (without recoding using `sox`), possibly followed by a recoding pass using `sox`. (Or, you could recode each first, of course.)

First, you create a pipe-separated list (string) of the file names,

```
files="$(ls -1 prefix_????.mp3 | tr '\n' '|')"
```

remove the final superfluous pipe,

```
files="${files%|}"
```

and feed them to `ffmpeg`, with no recoding:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:$files" -codec copy output.mp3
```

Note that you may wish to run

```
ulimit -n hard
```

to raise the number of open files to the maximum allowed for the current process (*hard limit*); you can query it using `ulimit -n`. (I don't recall whether `ffmpeg` `concat:` opens the sources sequentially or all at once.)

If you do this more than once, I'd put it all into a simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export LANG=C LC_ALL=C
if [ $# -le 2 -o "$1" = "-h" -o "$1" = "--help" ]; then
    exec >&2
    printf '\n'
    printf 'Usage: %s -h | --help ]\n' "$0"
    printf '       %s OUTPUT INPUT1 .. INPUTn\n' "$0"
    printf '\n'
    printf 'Inputs may be audio mp3 or MPEG media files.\n'
    printf '\n'
    exit 1
fi

output="$1"
shift 1
ulimit -n hard

inputs="$(printf '%s|' "${@}")"
inputs="${inputs%|}"

ffmpeg -i "concat:$inputs" -codec copy "$output"
retval=$?

if [ $retval -ne 0 ]; then
    rm -f "$output"
    echo "Failed!"
    exit $retval
fi

# To remove all inputs now, uncomment the following line:
# rm -f "${@}"
echo "Success."
exit 0
```

Note that because I use `-codec copy` instead of `-acodec copy`, the above should work for all kinds of MPEG files, not just mp3 audio files.

Comment: I accepted the answer, but I get this error `can't open input file `prefix_0098.mp3': Too many open files
Failed!`

Comment: @xralf: Reduce `s`; use for example `s=50` (instead of `s=100`).

Comment: This was the first thing I've done and there is still this error.

Comment: @xralf: You found a bug in my snippet; now fixed. I had `n >= s` (more files than we want in one sublist), when I obviously meant `n <= s`, immediately after the `# Slice files array` comment. (So, instead of slicing, it used the entire array for the first sublist. Ouch. Apologies for the idiotic bug.)

Comment: Yes, you're right. I wasn't thinking on it, but instead tried to test what is in `echo "${sub[@]}"` before `break`. But, thinking is better practise :-) if you're not multitasking like me today

Comment: I discovered other kind of problem. The more files, the more noise is in the resulting file. I noticed that the problem is because, there is a file we concatenate repeatedly. So, the solution is good logically, but from the listening point of view, the result is unusable. I wonder if sox has some switch to get rid of this problem. Or if the bash script can treat temporary files in a different way (not to use one temporary many times)

Comment: @xralf: The noise occurs, because you end up re-encoding the initial bit over and over again. You can minimize this by encoding the files in groups, and finally merging the groups. (Right now, the snippet re-encodes the initial part over and over again.)

Comment: A better solution would be to use e.g. `ffmpeg` to concatenate the files without re-encoding (and finally re-encode with `sox` if necessary or desired). First, combine the names into a pipe-separated list: `files="$(ls -1 prefix_????.mp3 | tr '\n' '|')"`, then remove the trailing pipe, `files="${files%|}"`, and finally run `ffmpeg -i "concat:$files" -acodec copy output.mp3` to concatenate them all into `output.mp3`.

Answer (score 2):

(edited for clarity, and to make it safer)

This should work if there are no gaps in the file sequence.  Just replace `LAST=0` with the last 4-digit number in your sequence.  You’ll be left with `script_name_output.mp3`.

```
# make a backup in case anything goes wrong
mkdir backup && cp *.mp3 backup

# enter last 4-digit number in the file sequence
LAST=0
LASTNN__=$(echo ${LAST:0:2})
LAST__NN=$(echo ${LAST:2:2})

# sox 100 files at a time
for i in $(seq -f "%02g" 0 $((--LASTNN__))); do
  LIST=$(paste -sd' ' <(seq -f "prefix_$i%02g.mp3" 0 99));
  sox $LIST script_name_output_$i.mp3;
done

# sox the last group
LAST_LIST=$(paste -sd' ' \
  <(seq -f "prefix_${LASTNN__}%02g.mp3" 0 $LAST__NN))
sox $LAST_LIST script_name_output_${LASTNN__}.mp3

# concatenate all the sox'ed files
OUTPUT_LIST=$(paste -sd' ' \
  <(seq -f "script_name_output_%02g.mp3" 0 $LASTNN__))
sox $OUTPUT_LIST script_name_output.mp3

# delete the intermediate files
rm $OUTPUT_LIST

# delete input files if everything worked
rm prefix_*.mp3
```

Comment: @xralf: I see you've put a bounty on this issue, and that "the current answers do not contain enough detail".  What details do you feel are missing from my answer?  I'm happy to clarify any confusion.  Have you tried running the first code block I provided?  Did it not work?

Comment: @xralf: I've updated my answer for clarity, and to make it safer.  Let me know if you're still unable to get it to work.

Comment: I accepted other solution because it was more universal and less cryptic (I'm not used to various bash shortcuts)

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to raise the file descriptor limit:

```
ulimit -n 11000
```

As a regular user, you should be able to raise that limit up to the *hard* limit. See `ulimit -Hn` for the current hard limit.

A non-root process cannot raise the hard limit (that's the whole point, the administrator sets it to prevent ordinary users to abuse the system resources). If you have superuser access via `sudo`, you can start a new non-superuser shell with the hard and soft limit raised with:

```
sudo HOME="$HOME" zsh -c 'ulimit -HSn 100000; USERNAME=$SUDO_USER; zsh'
```

Or that sox command:

```
sudo HOME="$HOME" zsh -c 'ulimit -HSn 100000; USERNAME=$SUDO_USER
                          sox prefix_*.mp3 script_name_output.mp3'
```

If on Linux, you can also call the `prlimit` command as root to raise the limit of your shell (and its children):

```
bash-4.3$ ulimit -n
1024
bash-4.3$ ulimit -Hn
65536
bash-4.3$ sudo prlimit --nofile=100000:100000 --pid="$$"
bash-4.3$ ulimit -Hn
100000
bash-4.3$ ulimit -n
100000
```

Otherwise, you could do the job in 2 steps: concatenate the files in groups of 347 files and then concatenate the intermediary files.

With `zsh`:

```
intermediate_concat() sox "$@" intermediate.$((++n)).mp3
autoload zargs
n=0
zargs -n 347 prefix_*.mp3 -- intermediate_concat
sox intermediate.*.mp3(n) script_name_output.mp3
```

Comment: That's strange. I used `ulimit -n 11000` at the beginning of my script and it writes `sox FAIL formats: can't open input file `prefix_0098.mp3': Too many open files`

Comment: `ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted` I overlooked this error at the beginning. Should I always use `sudo` for my script?

Comment: @xralf, see edit.